# How to derive errors in neural network with the backpropagation algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, backpropagation

From this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_Eamf8MHwU&list=PLLssT5z_DsK-h9vYZkQkYNWcItqhlRJLN&index=51) by Andrew Ng around 5:00

[image]

How are $\delta_3$ and $\delta_2$ derived? 
In fact, what does $\delta_3$ even mean? $\delta_4$ 
is got by comparing to y, no such comparison is possible
for the output of a hidden layer, right?

Comment: The video link is not working. Please, update it, or provide a link to the course. Thanks.

Comment: Though @tmangin answered it beautifully, still, if you want a more detailed explanation, you can refer to this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/chrismbryant/backpropagation). It is well explained and contains derivations to both the Machine Learning Course and the Deep Learning Specialization.

Answer (score 21):

I'm going to answer your question about the $\delta_i^{(l)}$, but remember that your question is a sub question of a larger question which is why:

$$\nabla_{ij}^{(l)} =  \sum_k \theta_{ki}^{(l+1)}\delta_k^{(l+1)}*(a_i^{(l)}(1-a_i^{(l)})) * a_j^{(l-1)}$$

**Reminder about the steps in Neural networks:**

- Step 1: forward propagation (calculation of the $a_{i}^{(l)}$)
- Step 2a: backward propagation: calculation of the errors $\delta_{i}^{(l)}$
- Step 2b: backward propagation: calculation of the gradient $\nabla_{ij}^{(l)}$ of J($\Theta$) using the errors $\delta_{i}^{(l+1)}$ and the $a_{i}^{(l)}$,
- Step 3: gradient descent: calculate the new $\theta_{ij}^{(l)}$ using the gradients $\nabla_{ij}^{(l)}$

**First,** to understand *what the $\delta_i^{(l)}$ are*, *what they represent* and *why Andrew NG it talking about them*, you need to understand what Andrew is actually doing at that pointand why we do all these calculations: **He's calculating the gradient $\nabla_{ij}^{(l)}$ of $\theta_{ij}^{(l)}$** to be used in the Gradient descent algorithm.

The gradient is defined as:

$$\nabla_{ij}^{(l)} = \dfrac {\partial C} {\partial \theta_{ij}^{(l)}}$$

As we can't really solve this formula directly, we are going to modify it using TWO MAGIC TRICKS to arrive at a formula we can actually calculate. This final usable formula is:

**$$\nabla_{ij}^{(l)} =  \theta^{(l+1)^T}\delta^{(l+1)}.*(a_i^{(l)}(1-a_i^{(l)})) * a_j^{(l-1)}$$**

**Note** : here mapping from 1st layer to 2nd layer is notated as **theta2** and so on, instead of **theta1** as in andrew ng coursera

To arrive at this result, the **FIRST MAGIC TRICK** is that we can write the gradient $\nabla_{ij}^{(l)}$ of $\theta_{ij}^{(l)}$ using $\delta_i^{(l)}$:

$$\nabla_{ij}^{(l)} = \delta_i^{(l)} * a_j^{(l-1)}$$
With $\delta_i^{(L)}$ defined (for the L index only) as:

$$ \delta_i^{(L)} = \dfrac {\partial C} {\partial z_i^{(l)}}$$

And then the **SECOND MAGIC TRICK** using the relation between $\delta_i^{(l)}$ and $\delta_i^{(l+1)}$, to defined the other indexes,

$$\delta_i^{(l)} = \theta^{(l+1)^T}\delta^{(l+1)}.*(a_i^{(l)}(1-a_i^{(l)})) $$

And as I said, we can finally write a formula for which we know all the terms:

$$\nabla_{ij}^{(l)} =  \theta^{(l+1)^T}\delta^{(l+1)}.*(a_i^{(l)}(1-a_i^{(l)})) * a_j^{(l-1)}$$

**DEMONSTRATION of the FIRST MAGIC TRICK:** $\nabla_{ij}^{(l)} = \delta_i^{(l)} * a_j^{(l-1)}$

We defined:

$$\nabla_{ij}^{(l)} = \dfrac {\partial C} {\partial \theta_{ij}^{(l)}}$$

Here, the [Generalized chain rule](https://mananshah99.github.io/blog/2020/08/15/backprop/) provides a way to write that equality as

$$\nabla_{ij}^{(l)} = \sum_k \dfrac {\partial C} {\partial z_k^{(l)}} * \dfrac {\partial z_k^{(l)}} {\partial \theta_{ij}^{(l)}}$$.

Note that this change is not obvious, but using the following intuition it becomes clearer:

The rate of change of the cost function $C$ with repect to a weighed input $z^l_j$ depends on all contributions $a^l_j$ that $z^l_j$ influences.

However, as:

$$ z_k^{(l)} = \sum_m \theta_{km}^{(l)} * a_m^{(l-1)} $$

Here:
m --> unit in layer *l* - 1    ;
k --> unit in layer *l*

```
  i --> unit in layer *l*
  j --> unit in layer *l*-1
```

We then can write:

$$\dfrac {\partial z_k^{(l)}} {\partial \theta_{ij}^{(l)}} = \dfrac {\partial}{\partial \theta_{ij}^{(l)}} \sum_m \theta_{km}^{(l)} * a_m^{(l-1)}$$

Because of the [linearity of the differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearity_of_differentiation) [ (u + v)' = u'+ v'], we can write:

$$\dfrac {\partial z_k^{(l)}} {\partial \theta_{ij}^{(l)}} = \sum_m\dfrac {\partial\theta_{km}^{(l)}} {\partial \theta_{ij}^{(l)}}* a_m^{(l-1)}  $$

with:
$$\text{if } k,m \neq i,j, \ \ \dfrac {\partial\theta_{km}^{(l)}} {\partial \theta_{ij}^{(l)}}* a_m^{(l-1)} = 0  $$

$$\text{if } k,m = i,j, \ \ \dfrac {\partial\theta_{km}^{(l)}} {\partial \theta_{ij}^{(l)}}* a_m^{(l-1)} = \dfrac {\partial\theta_{ij}^{(l)}} {\partial \theta_{ij}^{(l)}}* a_j^{(l-1)} = a_j^{(l-1)}  $$

Then for $k = i$ (otherwise it's clearly equal to zero):

$$\dfrac {\partial z_i^{(l)}} {\partial \theta_{ij}^{(l)}} = \dfrac {\partial\theta_{ij}^{(l)}} {\partial \theta_{ij}^{(l)}}* a_j^{(l-1)} + \sum_{m \neq j}\dfrac {\partial\theta_{im}^{(l)}} {\partial \theta_{ij}^{(l)}}* a_j^{(l-1)} =  a_j^{(l-1)} + 0 $$

Finally, for $k = i$:
$$\dfrac {\partial z_i^{(l)}} {\partial \theta_{ij}^{(l)}} = a_j^{(l-1)}$$

As a result, we can write our first expression of the gradient $\nabla_{ij}^{(l)}$:

$$\nabla_{ij}^{(l)} = \dfrac {\partial C} {\partial z_i^{(l)}} * \dfrac {\partial z_i^{(l)}} {\partial \theta_{ij}^{(l)}}$$

Which is equivalent to:

$$\nabla_{ij}^{(l)} =  \dfrac {\partial C} {\partial z_i^{(l)}} * a_j^{(l-1)}$$

Or:

$$\nabla_{ij}^{(l)} =  \delta_i^{(l)} * a_j^{(l-1)}$$

**DEMONSTRATION OF THE SECOND MAGIC TRICK**: $\delta_i^{(l)} = \theta^{(l+1)^T}\delta^{(l+1)}.*(a_i^{(l)}(1-a_i^{(l)})) $ or:

$$\delta^{(l)} = \theta^{(l+1)^T}\delta^{(l+1)}.*(a^{(l)}(1-a^{(l)})) $$

Remember that we posed:

$$ \delta^{(l)} = \dfrac {\partial C} {\partial z^{(l)}} \ \ \ and \ \ \ \delta_i^{(l)} = \dfrac {\partial C} {\partial z_i^{(l)}}$$

Again, the [Chain rule **for higher dimensions**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions) enables us to write:

$$ \delta_i^{(l)} = \sum_k \dfrac {\partial C} {\partial z_k^{(l+1)}} \dfrac {\partial z_k^{(l+1)}} {\partial z_i^{(l)}}$$

Replacing $\dfrac {\partial C} {\partial z_k^{(l+1)}}$ by $\delta_k^{(l+1)}$, we have:

$$ \delta_i^{(l)} = \sum_k  \delta_k^{(l+1)} \dfrac {\partial z_k^{(l+1)}} {\partial z_i^{(l)}}$$

Now, let's focus on $\dfrac {\partial z_k^{(l+1)}} {\partial z_i^{(l)}}$. We have:

$$ z_k^{(l+1)} = \sum_j  \theta_{kj}^{(l+1)} * a_j^{(l)}   = \sum_j  \theta_{kj}^{(l+1)} * g(z_j^{(l)}) $$

Then we derive this expression regarding $ z_k^{(i)}$:

$$ \dfrac {\partial z_k^{(l+1)}} {\partial z_i^{(l)}} = \dfrac {\partial \sum_j \theta_{kj}^{(l+1)} * g(z_j^{(l)}) }{\partial z_i^{(l)}} $$

Because of the linearity of the derivation, we can write:

$$ \dfrac {\partial z_k^{(l+1)}} {\partial z_i^{(l)}} = \sum_j \theta_{kj}^{(l+1)} * \dfrac {\partial g(z_j^{(l)}) }{\partial z_i^{(l)}} $$

If $j \neq i$, then $\dfrac {\partial \theta_{kj}^{(l+1)} * g(z_j^{(l)})} {\partial z_i^{(l)}} = 0 $

As a consequence:

$$ \dfrac {\partial z_k^{(l+1)}} {\partial z_i^{(l)}} = \dfrac {\theta_{ki}^{(l+1)} * \partial g(z_i^{(l)}) }{\partial z_i^{(l)}} $$

And then:

$$ \delta_i^{(l)} = \sum_k  \delta_k^{(l+1)} \theta_{ki}^{(l+1)} * \dfrac { \partial g(z_i^{(l)}) }{\partial z_i^{(l)}}$$

As $g'(z) = g(z)(1-g(z))$, we have:

$$ \delta_i^{(l)} = \sum_k  \delta_k^{(l+1)} \theta_{ki}^{(l+1)} * g(z_i^{(l)})(1-g(z_i^{(l)}) $$

And as $g(z_i^{(l)}) = a_i^{(l)}$, we have:

$$ \delta_i^{(l)} = \sum_k  \delta_k^{(l+1)} \theta_{ki}^{(l+1)} * a_i^{(l)}(1-a_i^{(l)}) $$

And finally, using the vectorized notation:

$$\nabla_{ij}^{(l)} =  [\theta^{(l+1)^T}\delta^{(l+1)}*(a_i^{(l)}(1-a_i^{(l)}))] * [a_j^{(l-1)}]$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I upvoted you !! Could you please cite the sources you referred for arriving at the answer... :)

Comment: @tmangin : Following Andrew Ng talk, we have $\delta_j^{(i)}$ is the error of node j in layer l. How did you get the definition of $\delta_j^{(i)}=\frac{\partial C}{\partial Z_j^{(l)}}$.

Comment: @phuong Actually, I you're right to ask: only the $$ \delta_i^{(L)} $$ with the highest "l" index L is defined as $$ \delta_i^{(L)} = \dfrac {\partial C} {\partial z_i^{(l)}}$$
Whereas the deltas with lower "l" indexes are defined by the following formula: $$\delta_i^{(l)} = \theta^{(l+1)^T}\delta^{(l+1)}.*(a_i^{(l)}(1-a_i^{(l)})) $$

Comment: I highly recommend reading the [backprop](https://sudeepraja.github.io/Neural/) vectorial notation of calculating the gradients.

Comment: Your final usable formula is not what Andrew Ng had, which is making it really frustrating to follow your proof. He had ∇(l)ij=θ(l)Tδ(l+1).∗(a(l)i(1−a(l)i))∗a(l−1)j, not θ(l+1)Tδ(l+1)

Comment: @tmangin thx, it really helps!